# Places Api 's Autocomplete dismissed when user click on any area except results

Tags: android, google-places-autocomplete

I have Places Api 's Autocomplete it works fine and show results, but when it first open and no query from user, when he clicks on any place on screen it close itself

[image: Image show area where user click]

when i change **mode** to **OVERLAY**
i got this

[image: with overlay]

it seems with FULL_MODE and when *user click* below *search area*, Place API  treats it like in **OVERLAY** so it *closes* screen

version

`implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'`

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried to **downgrade**/**upgrade** version of library  as I saw some apps has this behavior

Solution is to use

`implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'`